# Tree ASCII Art in Java

Tags: java, loops, ascii

im writing a code where i need to use 3 loops, one must be a double nested loop, to create an asciiart of anything I would like. I'm trying to make a christmas tree, and once i broke it down into segments, i realize im kind of stuck and not sure how to proceed.

```
    public class christmas_tree{

  public static void main (String[] args) {
  first_triangle();
  second_triangle();
  third_triangle();
  //tree_base();
  }

  public static void first_triangle() {
    int size = 10;
    for (int line_number = 0; line_number < size; line_number++) {
      for (int spaces = 0; spaces < size - line_number; spaces++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (int stars = 0; stars < 1 + 2 * line_number; stars++) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
  }
  public static void second_triangle() {
    int size = 15;
    for (int line_number = (size - 10); line_number < size; line_number++) {
      for (int spaces = 0; spaces < size - line_number; spaces++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (int stars = 0; stars < 1 + 2 * line_number; stars++) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
  }
  public static void third_triangle() {
    int size = 20;
    for (int line_number = (size - 10); line_number < size; line_number++) {
      for (int spaces = 0; spaces < size - line_number; spaces++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (int stars = 0; stars < 1 + 2 * line_number; stars++) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
  }
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to make a christmas tree"* What does a Christmas tree look like in ASCII Art? If you (and we) don't know what the goal is, how would you (and we) know if the code is correct, or how to fix it? **Edit** the question and show us what the *expected* output is, and what you code is *actually* printing.

Comment: Why do you need 3 identical copies of the same method? Wouldn't it be better and easier to have one copy that takes the `size` as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an inspiration for your future learning, using Java 11 method [`repeat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)), I believe the Christmas tree can be printed with code that is this simple:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printTriangle(10, 0, 10);
    printTriangle(5, 5, 15);
    printTriangle(0, 10, 20);
    printSquare(15, 9, 4);
}
static void printTriangle(int indent, int start, int size) {
    for (int row = start; row < size; row++)
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(size - row - 1 + indent) + "*".repeat(1 + 2 * row));
}
static void printSquare(int indent, int width, int height) {
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(indent) + "*".repeat(width));
}
```

*Output*

```
                   *
                  ***
                 *****
                *******
               *********
              ***********
             *************
            ***************
           *****************
          *******************
              ***********
             *************
            ***************
           *****************
          *******************
         *********************
        ***********************
       *************************
      ***************************
     *****************************
         *********************
        ***********************
       *************************
      ***************************
     *****************************
    *******************************
   *********************************
  ***********************************
 *************************************
***************************************
               *********
               *********
               *********
               *********
```

---

**UPDATE**

Same logic that will work in all Java versions, by using a home-built `repeat` method:

```java
static void printTriangle(int indent, int start, int size) {
    for (int row = start; row < size; row++)
        System.out.println(repeat(' ', size - row - 1 + indent) + repeat('*', 1 + 2 * row));
}
static void printSquare(int indent, int width, int height) {
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        System.out.println(repeat(' ', indent) + repeat('*', width));
}
static String repeat(char c, int count) {
    char[] buf = new char[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        buf[i] = c;
    return new String(buf);
}
```

Or perhaps, closer to the intended way(?), using `for` loop with `print` calls, but moving the simple print loops to reusable helper method, to void repeating the same code many times, and to improve the clarity of what the code is doing:

```java
static void printTriangle(int indent, int start, int size) {
    for (int row = start; row < size; row++) {
        print(" ", size - row - 1 + indent);
        print("*", 1 + 2 * row);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
static void printSquare(int indent, int width, int height) {
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        print(" ", indent);
        print("*", width);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
static void print(String s, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an amazing way of printing the image i want! However I need to use nested loops. Repeat is not something in my arsenal unfortunately. Would I be able to use a nested loops for the print triangle instead?

Comment: @Wontoonsin Yes you would. You're already doing (some of) it. It's just a lot more code.